# How do I enforce blank lines around non-orphaned braces in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

The Eclipse format tool (Luna) does not account for

1. Enforcing 1 blank line *before and after* a non-orphaned brace on non-function declaration.

`for (...) {`, `if (...) {`, `} else {`, `} catch (...) {`

2. Enforcing 0 blank lines before an orphaned closing brace `}`.
3. Enforcing 1 blank line after an orphaned closing brace, except when followed by another orphaned closing brace (rule 2 trumping rule 3).

*Terminology:*

- non-orphaned = paired with operator/keyword
- non-function = not a class or method declaration

Example:

```
                ...
                someCall();
            } // ORPHAN CLOSE BRACE - NO BLANK LINE BEFORE OR AFTER
        } // ORPHAN CLOSE BRACE – BLANK LINE AFTER 

        someOtherCall();
    } // ORPHAN CLOSE BRACE – NO BLANK LINE BEFORE

    ...
    String result;
    int foo = 1000;
                                           // a blank line
    for (int x = 0; x < foo; x++) {
                                           // a blank line
        if (x < value) {
                                           // a blank line
            try {
                                           // a blank line
                result = methodCall(x);
                result.setBar(outtaReach);
                handleResult(x, result);
                x = z % 5;
                                           // a blank line
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                           // a blank line
                doSomething(x, ex);        // no blank line - orphan
            }
                                           // a blank line
        } else {
                                           // a blank line
            otherCall(x);                  // no blank line - orphan
        }                                  // no blank line - orphan
    }
                                           // a blank line
    ...
```

My reasons for this are to enhance code readability; I'll let the JVM handle optimization.  Opinions regarding my desired formatting style aside, **is there a way to enforce this particular blank line style within Eclipse?**  Perhaps there is a plug-in to do this that I haven't yet found, or would I have to code one?

The "Blank Lines" section of the Java Code Formatter of Eclipse does not provide the ability to enforce or apply this.  Of note, I don't want to force blank lines between code blocks that do not have braces (see the `String | int` and `result | handleResult()` code blocks above as examples).

Closest settings I have to this is:

> Blank lines in compilation unit
>
> - Before package declaration: 0
> - After package declaration: 1
> - Before import declaration: 1
> - Between import groups: 0
> - After import declaration: 1
> - Between class declarations: 1
>
> Blank lines within class declarations
>
> - Before first declaration: 1
> - Before declarations of the same kind: 1
> - Before member class declarations: 1
> - Before field declarations: 0
> - Before method declarations: 1
> - At beginning of method body: 1
>
> Existing blank lines
>
> - Number of empty lines to preserve: 1

Comment: I know it doesn't help anything, but why?

Comment: @Trengot I've been looking for something like this for ages, it helps alot with readability. I like to know the answer too

Comment: @Trengot - as nafas says, natural readability.

Comment: Ok, personal preference I guess. Looks really confusing to me.

Comment: @Trengot - Out of curiosity, is it the rule enforcement structure or the resulting code output that appears confusing to you, and how so?

Comment: @JoshDM, The resulting code layout. I find having loads of extra blank lines within code blocks breaks the code up and makes it harder to see each block as a coherent 'lump' of code.

Comment: The blank lines aren't internal to the blocks themselves, if a block is defined as a run of code enclosed within braces.  There is nothing breaking up those "blocks".  The blank line basically follows or precedes a jump in indentation.

Comment: @JoshDM I'm guessing you haven't found an answer for this yet... :(

Comment: Sorry @nafas, no. Apparently everyone hates my spacing desires though, according to the high number of votes Trengot's comment has gained.

Comment: @JoshDM well, right now I'm doing what you are asking  manually and I hate it, it would have been great if it could be automated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [JIndent plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jindent-source-code-formatter-javacc); it's commercial but it might be able to achieve the complex rules you're looking for.

Comment: Was hoping for something without a cost attached.

Answer (score 1):

`Uncrustify` should be able to do this.  Unfortunately it's not available as an Eclipse plugin

http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/